# How to turn off or disable text font anti aliasing or smoothing globally or just for one app?

Tags: system, fonts, user-interface, accessibility, text-layout

How do I turn off font smoothing globally or just for one app like firefox?

Can it be done with a mod like cyanogenmod or xposed framework?